# How to put SQL table data on QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qt5.4

this code gives me the exact cell count with tables heders. but not table data. is there any way to get SQL data to Qtableview?

code :

```
if(db.open()){
    qDebug() << "Opened!!";
    QSqlQuery *query = new QSqlQuery(db);
    query->prepare("SELECT COUNT(Id) AS Student_Count, Gender  FROM Students GROUP BY Gender;");
    query->exec();
    QSqlQueryModel* model = new QSqlQueryModel();
    ui->tableView->setModel(model);
    model->setQuery(*query);
    qDebug() << model->rowCount();


    db.close();
}else{
    qDebug() << "Error : " << db.lastError().text();
}
```

Output : [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5zBZ.png)

Comment: You will need a query that returns the table data that you are looking for. Then use `query->value()` to get the information. Deconstruction that QVariant as needed and populate the table one by one.

Comment: @Aditya query is providing the required data. I checked that using qDebug();

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-presenting.html